# Indicator Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: indicator

I have installed indicator-multiload but it doesn't show up.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

I also tryed to remove it and reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-multiload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to restart Gnome-shell with 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> , type "r" then Enter.
Or (better) you can simply reboot your system.